# reorganizing list of dataframes

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of `n` dataframes

```
mylist = [None]*3
mylist[0] = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]],columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
mylist[1] = pd.DataFrame(data=[[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]],columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
mylist[2] = pd.DataFrame(data=[[21,22,23,24,25],[26,27,28,29,30]],columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
```

each dataframe contains `x` columns and `y` rows

I would like to transform `mylist` in `mylist_transf`
that has as many dataframes as the columns of `mylist`. the first dataframe of `mylist_transf` should contain the first columns of the dataframes in `mylist`, the second dataframe the second columns etc. etc.

the desired output is the following...

```
mylist_transf = [None]*5
mylist_transf[0] = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,6],[11,16],[21,26]],columns=['0','1'])
mylist_transf[1] = pd.DataFrame(data=[[2,7],[12,17],[22,27]],columns=['0','1'])
mylist_transf[2] = pd.DataFrame(data=[[3,8],[13,18],[23,28]],columns=['0','1'])
mylist_transf[3] = pd.DataFrame(data=[[4,9],[14,19],[24,29]],columns=['0','1'])
mylist_transf[4] = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5,10],[15,20],[25,30]],columns=['0','1'])
```

I am looking to do this in a pythonic way (I have many many dataframes in `mylist`)
If possible I would also to assign the name `'a','b','c','d','e'` to the new 5 list entries of `mylist_transf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat, group the columns, then split and reset_index i.e

```
new_list = [i.T.reset_index(drop=True) for _,i in pd.concat(mylist,1).groupby(axis=1,level=0)]
```

Output :

```
new_list[0]
#    0   1
#0   1   6
#1  11  16
#2  21  26
new_list[1]
#    0   1 
#0   2   7
#1  12  17
#2  22  27
new_list[4]
#    0   1
#0   5  10
#1  15  20
#2  25  30
```